# Adobe Animate JS Fix?

Tags: javascript, adobe

JS Nembie,

I created a banner in Adobe Animate. But when I submit to Validator, it has the following error.

```
URL_FETCH_NOT_ALLOWED: https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js
```

Because the generated HTML file has:

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="Untitled-1.js"></script>
```

But if I delete this:

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
```

It breaks. And if I combine the 2 JS, Validator kicks it out because it's too big.

I'm green, but is there a basic part of this

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
```

That I can combine with

```
<script src="Untitled-1.js"></script>
```

And get it to work? Thanks for the Help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Replaced

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
```

with Google hosted:

```
<script src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/cached_libs/createjs_2019.11.15_min.js"></script>
```

This fixed my issue.

Cheers!